# [SP2016][Office Online Server] Web Apps don't work on SharePoint https sites

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, https, office-online-server

I have issues with my lab environment where I have set redirection from http to https. Everything works fine until I try to open documents in web apps. I am getting error that there was a problem and document cannot be opened.

Here is short overview of how I set up redirection:

1. Added new binding in IIS for my web application (https, port 443 and certificate)
2. AAM settings:

   **a)Internal URL**:https://servername, Zone:Default, Public URL:https://servername

   **b)Internal URL**:http://servername, Zone:Default, Public URL:https://servername

Office farm configuration:

[image]

*WOPI zone has been set to internal-https.*

Logs from  OOS:

> 02/06/2019 08:54:12.65    w3wp.exe (0x3AB4)                           0x2738  Office Online                   Collab Sandboxing               buqay   Medium      Wopi,CheckFile,WACSERVER HttpRequestAsyncException [url:UREDACTED_(vHKPAP1SI77bjR6MgrgTYoLULPb0bcptKBENxaaj3dA=), e:Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.HttpRequestAsyncException: No Response in WebException ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.     at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)     at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)     at Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.HttpRequestAsync.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---] 9a3fbd9e-4066-604e-f675-99afa0e09b9f
>   02/06/2019 08:54:12.65    w3wp.exe (0x3AB4)                           0x2738  Office Online                   Collab Sandboxing               adhsk   Unexpected  WOPI CheckFile: Catch-All Failure [exception:Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.EnvironmentAdapters.UnexpectedErrorException: HttpRequest failed. ---> Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.HttpRequestAsyncException: No Response in WebException ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.     at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)     at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)     at Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.HttpRequestAsync.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.WopiTalky.AddHostResponseDataAndThrow(Exception exception, HttpRequestAsyncResult result)     at Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.WopiTalky.LogAndThrowWireException(HttpRequestAsyncResult result, HttpRequestAsyncException delayedException)     at Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.WopiDocument.LogAndThrowWireException(HttpRequestAsyncResult result, HttpRequestAsyncException delayedException)     at Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.HttpRequestAsync.End()     at Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.WopiDocument.CheckWopiFile()]  9a3fbd9e-4066-604e-f675-99afa0e09b9f
>   02/06/2019 08:54:12.65    w3wp.exe (0x3AB4)                           0x2738  Office Online                   Collab Sandboxing               ajjve   Medium      WOPI CheckFile: Catch-All Failure [url:UREDACTED_(6UnYFVPmv6zdLFtOUT4YJEYsPRvdiT0O6frvZoEsQhM=)]    9a3fbd9e-4066-604e-f675-99afa0e09b9f
>   02/06/2019 08:54:12.65    w3wp.exe (0x3AB4)                           0x2738  Office Online                   Word Online DocX Common         ann56   Medium      Setting Completion: [Operation:WacCheckFile] [CompletedSuccessfully:False] [RootOperation:] [StartTime:02/06/2019 07:54:12.612] [DurationInMilliseconds:39] [SizeInBytes:0] [ExtraInfo:]    9a3fbd9e-4066-604e-f675-99afa0e09b9f
>   02/06/2019 08:54:12.65    w3wp.exe (0x3AB4)                           0x2738  Services Infrastructure         Services Infrastructure Br Err  bsl5f   Medium      BaseDocument::LogSessionMetrics: {"ApplicationLCID":"pl-PL","BrowserLCID":"pl-PL","DataLCID":"en-US"}   9a3fbd9e-4066-604e-f675-99afa0e09b9f
>   02/06/2019 08:54:12.65    w3wp.exe (0x3AB4)                           0x2738  Office Online                   Collab Sandboxing               axvdb   Medium      CheckFailureCache.IncrementCheckFailureCount  Doc: e02f7b7c23e308eeaca7d4921b409b72f6a1fc0a5f729604cb5a51af65ef2121 User: IREDACTED 9a3fbd9e-4066-604e-f675-99afa0e09b9f
>   02/06/2019 08:54:12.65    w3wp.exe (0x3AB4)                           0x2738  Services Infrastructure         Services Infrastructure Br Err  b66ra   Unexpected  FileUnknownException with InnerException from CheckBaseDocument, InnerException: Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.EnvironmentAdapters.UnexpectedErrorException: HttpRequest failed. ---> Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.HttpRequestAsyncException: No Response in WebException ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.     at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)     at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)     at Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.HttpRequestAsync.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.WopiTalky.AddHostResponseDataAndThrow(Exception exception, HttpRequestAsyncResult result)     at Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.WopiTalky.LogAndThrowWireException(HttpRequestAsyncResult result, HttpRequestAsyncException delayedException)     at Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.WopiDocument.LogAndThrowWireException(HttpRequestAsyncResult result, HttpRequestAsyncException delayedException)     at Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.HttpRequestAsync.End()     at Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.WopiDocument.CheckWopiFile()   9a3fbd9e-4066-604e-f675-99afa0e09b9f

I read some articles (e.g. [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/279630e0-1299-4ef9-bc2c-3eddc0c15dbf/issue-with-sharepoint-2013-office-web-apps-2013-and-redirected-urls?forum=sharepointadmin)) that adding http path as intranet zone may resolve issue, but in my scenario it removes redirection from http to https.

How can I configure it to make it work? I suppose that better option would be to extend my web application to SSL (I have done it for another web app and web apps work there), but I am wondering whether it is possible to perform it without creating separate site.

*Thanks in advance for advice.*

Comment: Please post your OfficeOnlineServer configuration here by running `Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm` on OOS-Server

Comment: I have updated my post

Comment: Configuration looks OK. OOS has it's own ULS-Log (see `LogLocation`). Please post the correlation of a failed error here.

Comment: Correlation stack added

Answer (score 0):

The internal/external wopi zones are a reference to the OOS config, not your AAMs. For example, connect to:

http://yourofficeonlineserver/hosting/discovery

And check the output of the above. It should indicate how its configured (internal/external/http/https/etc.) Then, run the following on the SharePoint server to compare:

get-spwopizone
get-spwopibinding

The output of all of the above needs to match.

Comment: Hello Mike, like I wrote, web apps work fine on another web application where I have extended it to SSL. It doesn't work in one scenario: when I am accessing it from web application where I have set bindings and AAMs to redirect me from http to https (so it works perfectly for http sites etc.)

Answer (score 0):

OfficeOnlineServer doesn't trust SharePoint's SSL-Certificate:

> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

As you have the issue in a lab environment, i expect you used a self-signed certificate. This isn't trusted by another machine by default. You have several solutions to get SharePoint trusted by OOS:

- Download the Certificate and import it on OOS-Server as `Trusted Root Authority`. This is a little dirty, but makes least work.
- Deploy an own Certification Authority (CA) in your Lab-Environment and issue a SSL-Certificate there. If all machines are joined to the same domain, they will trust all certificates issues by your CA.
- Buy an 'official' certificate from a company like Digicert, Comodo, ...

Comment: I decided to extend web application to SSL. When I access sites using both protocols (without URL rewrite redirection) everything works fine and I am able to open documents in browser on both protocols. Once I enable rewrite rule web apps stop working (even after adding Sharepoint cert to the trusted authorities on OOS server). I cannot comprehend this. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean with `enable rewrite rule`? Did you implement IIS-Rewrite module? I also see some discrepancy between your original post (the not-extended-site doesn't work) vs. your comment (extended-site with rewrite doesn't work).